# How to remove errors in after_validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I want the ability to set some values on my model to null if they fail validation.  I have my model set up something like this:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :should_set_fields_to_null_if_invalid

  NULL_IF_INVALID_FIELDS = [:address, :phone]

  after_validation :set_fields_to_null_if_invalid, if: :should_set_fields_to_null_if_invalid
  ...
  # custom validations for address and phone
  ...

  def set_fields_to_null_if_invalid
    NULL_IF_INVALID_FIELDS.each do |attribute|
      self[attribute] = nil if errors.key?(attribute)
      errors.delete(attribute)
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, I am removing the error if it exists and set the attribute to null but I'm getting the following errors:

```
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: 
     # /Users/albertjankowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:80:in `raise_validation_error'
     # /Users/albertjankowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:53:in `save!'
```

Not sure why it is still failing without a validation message.  Does anyone have a suggestion on implementing this?

Comment: Why don't you nullify those invalid attributes before validation? Otherwise, your validation will fail or not fail depending on the order in which those validations are run.

Comment: I would need to know that they are invalid so I would need to run validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by instead of using `after_validation`, I just just used `validation`:

```
  after_validation :set_fields_to_null_if_invalid, if: :should_set_fields_to_null_if_invalid
```

to

```
  validate :set_fields_to_null_if_invalid, if: :should_set_fields_to_null_if_invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

You save the record with `save!` which raises an exception... so your `after_validation` method is never executed. You could use the `save` method instead of `save!`, or else you could rescue the exception and fix the attribute values:

```rb
begin
  @my_model_instance.save!
rescue
  # fix the problematic attributes and save again
end
```

However, validations are normally used to inform the user that they need to fix something in their input. A better way is simply to test the address and phone attributes and fix them if they fail the test, without using ActiveRecord's validation scheme, like this:

```rb
class MyModelController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # read csv file
    @my_model = MyModel.new(...params from csv file...)
    @my_model.address = nil unless @my_model.valid_imported_address?
    @my_model.phone = nil unless @my_model.valid_imported_phone?
    @my_model.save!
  end
end

class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  def valid_imported_address?
    # some test for compliant address, return true if acceptable
  end

  def valid_imported_phone?
    # some test for compliant phone, return true if acceptable
  end
end
```

Comment: The after_validation method does get executed and I confirm that it changes the value and removes the error item but still fails.

I am importing data from a csv and would like to blank out the value if it isn't valid so I don't have the ability to have someone fix it.  Also, I would like for validation to run one.

Comment: "I don't have the ability to have someone fix it"! You can "fix it" in your code!

Comment: LOL True you got me there,  but trying to come up with a way that I don't have to run the validations multiple times and save multiple times.

Comment: OK I've edited my answer to show an outline of how you might do it. The thing is that ActiveRecord validations aren't well suited to this scenario b/c there's no user involved. But if you really want to use the validations, you can use `begin... rescue... end` to rescue from the validation exception.